# compile error expected list seperator

Tags: html, vba, excel, excel-2010

Trying to modify a macro I have in excel and I am running into a problem with it. I am getting the message "Compile Error: Expected: list separator"

Here is the working vba code

```
Sub GetTitles()
    Dim c As Range, url As String
    For Each c In Columns("B").Cells
        url = Trim(c.Value)
        If LCase(url) Like "http://*" Then
            c.Offset(0, 4).Value = GetTitle(url)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
Function GetTitle(sURL As String)
    Dim title As String, res As String, pos1, pos2
    Dim objHttp As Object
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
    objHttp.Send ""

    res = objHttp.ResponseText
    pos1 = InStr(1, UCase(res), "<TITLE>")
    pos2 = InStr(1, UCase(res), "</TITLE>")

    title = ""
    If pos1 > 0 And pos2 > 0 Then
        pos1 = pos1 + Len("<TITLE>")
        title = Mid(res, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
    End If
    GetTitle = title
End Function
```

And it works great at getting the title of a list of HTML pages. I wish to extend the functionality and get the description of the pages as well. Sample meta description tag is like this `<meta name="dcterms.description" content="Description of Page"/>`

If I modify that sub and function like so, this is when I get the error.

```
Sub GetDesc()
    Dim c As Range, url As String
    For Each c In Columns("B").Cells
        url = Trim(c.Value)
        If LCase(url) Like "http://*" Then
            c.Offset(0, 4).Value = GetDesc(url)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
Function GetDesc(sURL As String)
    Dim title As String, res As String, pos1, pos2
    Dim objHttp As Object
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
    objHttp.Send ""

    res = objHttp.ResponseText
    pos1 = InStr(1, UCase(res), "<meta name="dcterms.description" content="")
    pos2 = InStr(1, UCase(res), ""/>")

    title = ""
    If pos1 > 0 And pos2 > 0 Then
        pos1 = pos1 + Len("<TITLE>")
        title = Mid(res, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
    End If
    GetTitle = title
End Function
```

So how would I get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the quotes where they are within a quoted string in VBA - so:

```
pos1 = InStr(1, LCase(res), "<meta name=""dcterms.description"" content=""")
pos2 = InStr(pos1, LCase(res), """/>")
```

Comment: The function runs, but returns blanks/does not put value in cell, what could be going wrong?

Comment: You'll get blanks where one of the search strings isn't found.

Comment: it returns blank for all of them, but there is a description in each html file...

Comment: Step through the code and see which variable is set to 0.

Comment: everything works fine until the GetTitle = title, which in this sub, I renamced GetDesc = desc. That is where the 0 value is.

Comment: What value is in your `desc` variable? Did the code step through the `If pos1 > 0 And pos2 > 0 Then...End If` code?

Comment: pos1 = 0, pos2 = 188, len = 35, title = "", GetDesc = Empty

Comment: Does not change anything if I do. I can use it to look for <h1> or <h2> and it works great. I think there is something screwy with all the "...

Comment: It needs to be LCase since the search text is lower case. If pos1 is 0 that text isn't in the html

Comment: ok, if I use Lcase, and search for the <meta charset="utf-8"/> using "<meta charset=""") and """/>") it returns utf-8 perfectly. However, if I try the "<meta name=""dcterms.description"" content=""""") and "/>") or """/>") it returns empty. And just for a sanity check, there is content in that meta tag.

Comment: If found the problem! It's that the position 2, namely the /> is found BEFORE the meta description, so it returns empty!

So the question becomes, how can I get the proper termination? Can I have a "meta name="dcterms.description"" content="*"/>) kinda thing?

Comment: Alright so that fixed that problem, not I get another one. Invalid Procedure Call or Argument, and It only appears with "<meta name=""dcterms.description"" content="""""). If I use "<meta name=""dcterms.description""") it works, but returns the content=" with it.

I guess were not escaping that one right, but how?

Thanks!

Comment: On which line? If it's on the `Mid` line then I'd guess you're ending up with a negative value at the end.

Comment: What is happening is that with "<meta name=""dcterms.description"" content="""""), pos1 = 0, so when we try to get pos2 it get's mad. There is something it does not like with that "<meta name=""dcterms.description"" content="""""). It seems the content section is a problem, because if I remove it, it's fine, but displays content="Foo

Comment: Got it fixed, needed "<meta name=""dcterms.description"" content="""). Please edit your answer so I can mark it off as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it right now, but this should do the trick. If it doenst work, maybe you get the idea of how  it works. So I'll try to explain what this piece of code actually does.

It looks up the position of the string [content="] and the position of the string ["/>], cuts out whatever is between those strings and puts it into [title] (a name you might want to change)

```
res = objHttp.ResponseText
pos1 = InStr(1, res, "content=""")
pos2 = InStr(1, res, """/>")

title = ""
If pos1 > 0 And pos2 > 0 Then
    pos1 = pos1 + Len("content=""")
    title = Mid(res, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
End If
'dont forget to change the function name
'and change it to something different to your sub name
GetDescr = title

End Function
```